# messaging_optins webhook event not working for messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I'm trying to get the event when the developer/tester/admin click on the messenger plugin to start the chat.

these are the selected event with my app:

Selected events: `messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins`

from these 3 events, two are working perfectly. but `messaging_optins` isn't working.

**from the documentation:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_optins

> This callback will occur when the send to Messenger plugin has been
>   tapped, a user has accepted a message request using customer matching,
>   or a user has opted in to receive messages via the checkbox plugin.

I'm tapping on the start chat button with a different developer account. but every time it fails to send me the webhook for this. but other 2 hooks are working perfectly!

Can you guys please help me with that?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? We are using Checkbox Plugin and have issues with webhooks, it's not being triggered at all.

Comment: Not yet :( I think it's their issue.

Comment: @consigliere I have also created an issue to there. if you do support and upvote then this might help to expose this issue. thanks
https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger/issues/227

Comment: Try create a bug report in https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: @ssakash Thank you for your suggestion. I will do create a bug report.

Comment: @CodeCooker , did this ever work out for you? I'm facing the same problem four years later!

Comment: @DavidTresner-Kirsch Hi, I'm sorry to say but it didn't work for me either! and after then I haven't tried anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You'll need to setup webhook subscription for each page as well.
As you can see in image, I have subscribed to "messaging_optins" on "Configure webhooks" section and "Generate access tokens" section as well.